# LaTeX Error: File `enumitem.sty' not found

Tags: errors, packages

I'm using the `enumitem` package, by typing `\usepackage{enumitem}` in the preamble, so when I compile my PDF two pop-up pages appear in order to install it. I click on "Install" for both however then the following error occurs:

```
LaTeX Error: File `enumitem.sty' not found.
```

If I try it again I get the same result. I've also tried it with the `cancel` package to no avail as well.

How can I effectively install this package for usage?

Comment: That is hard to say when you give us no information about what kind of LaTeX system you are using. MikTeX? TeXLive? Windows, Mac or Linux?

Comment: Windows, and MikTeX package manager. I'm using Knitr in case it's relevant.

Comment: Then use the package manager to install the missing packages. Normally MikTeX gives you a popup asking you if you want it to install it for you, but running LaTeX from within Knitr might block this popup. So either install the package using the package manager or try compiling the generated LaTeX file manually instead of having knitr doing it for you.

Comment: Thanks. Now when I install the package using the packing manager there's another "MiKTeX Problem Report" pop-up which reads `=get host by name failed in tcp.connect()`.

Comment: Pas, i don't use miktex, so cannot help, try googling that error

Comment: seems to be a common error for r/knitr users can you use the console cmd.exe and enter> ipconfig /all and check about 5 lines down that Wins proxy enabled...:No --- If it is yes can you identify why?

Comment: Do you have any news for us? Is your issue solved? How?